# How to call a variable inside function that inside .then

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying some ways to call a variable within `.then` but I can't get the solution. Here's my code:

```
const translate = require('translate-api');
var english;
let transText = 'buku';
var trans = transText;
translate.getText(trans,{to: 'en'}).then(function(text){
  gg = text.text;
  return gg;
});
```

Comment: Please add more detail on what you want to achieve here

Comment: Yes, this question is not clear. But try this : `return translate.getText(trans,{to: 'en'})`

Comment: First thing to realise is that it is not a question of **how**, it is a question of **when**. The code insiude `.then()` executes in the future.

Comment: Sry i wasn't clear. I Want to call gg variable

Comment: what did you want to call it?